# Compare values in two columns with Pandas

Tags: pandas, compare

I have 37k rows in my DataFrame. I need to compare the values in two columns to determine whether the prices are the same or different. I also need to print out the ones that are different.

So basically my table consist of three columns. Name, Price1 and Price2. I need to know which ones are not identical.

Can't seem to find anything in the documentation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: add an example, show what you have and what do you expect to see at the end.

Comment: `df[df['Price1'] != df['Price2']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be creating a third column that is boolean and that identifies the cases where `Price1` is different from `Price2` :

```
df["is_diff"] = df["Price1"] != df["Price2"]
```

Then, if you want to look at the cases where the two prices are different, you can display a DataFrame showing only these cases with:

```
df[df["is_diff"] == True]
```

Comment: `"is_diff"` already contains `True`/`False` so `df[df["is_diff"]]` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

#### `numpy.isclose`

Since prices are likely to be float values, they might not be exactly the same but close enough that you'd like to consider them the same.  You can use `np.isclose` to determine if they are within tolerance.

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.isclose(df['Price1'], df['Price2'])
df[~mask]
```

Then default absolute tolerance is `1e-08` and relative tolerance is `1e-05`.  [See documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

But you can change it if you want the absolute tolerance to be within `1e-06`

```
mask = np.isclose(df['Price1'], df['Price2'], atol=1e-06)
df[~mask]
```